If I am running a survey with multiple sections, am I collecting "attitude" or "attitudes"?
I am a researcher and I'm writing a report about the pharmaceutical industry. I am running a survey among the general public and it has three distinct sections. The sections are things like:

Your doctor and how they prescribe medicine
Your pharmacy and customer service
Pharmaceutical companies and their pricing levels

I have a name for the survey but I cant decide which one is more appropriate because I see the report has having three distinct sections:
Public Attitude on the Pharmaceutical Industry
or
Public Attitudes on the Pharmaceutical Industry

Are you trying to determine a person's overall attitude, or to describe several different attitudes that they may have?

Does this answer your question? Should I use the plural in "the dependence(s) of a and b on x"? Or 'Uniform weights on all edges' or 'uniform weights on each edge' or 'uniform ...?

Or perhaps especially 'Everybody's using a cell phone nowadays' vs 'Everybody's using cell phones nowadays?

Comments have been moved to chat; please do not continue the discussion here. Before posting a comment below this one, please review the purposes of comments. Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an answer, on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

The survey is completed by several different members of the public. The answers will differ, even if the questionnaire has only a single question. Hence the phrase must include the plural:

attitudes

The most appropriate preposition in my experience§ is “to” (certainly not “on”, and no need to inflate to toward as suggested in a comment), so:

Public attitudes to the pharmaceutical industry

§Cambridge has “to” and “towards”, but not “on”.

None is wrong, but using the plural attitudes may sound overcorrect to some. For a title, Public Attitude is unambiguous. Of course the attitude differs from person to person, just as when you say Public opinion. Take this sentence from The Electoral Commission in the UK:

Public Opinion Tracker 2023
Since 2007, the Electoral Commission has been tracking public attitudes towards different aspects of elections and democracy in the UK.

Here, I would argue that attitudes is used in the plural because it concerns different aspects. If the issue was one, public attitude would have probably been enough.
But at the end of the day, you must choose the version that best corresponds to what you want to stress. If you want to emphasise the diversity of opinion, rather than the overall, prevailing opinion of the public, maybe the plural would be more striking.
Also, as you see in the example quoted above, I would use the preposition towards after attitude(s). With on, the noun view(s) would go better.

Plural attitudes is so commonly used with reports of surveys that I wonder what makes you think it might sound overcorrect?
